# Topology of sphere with identification of the equator to a point

Tags: general-topology

I have stumbled across this exercise:

Let $\mathbb{R}^3 \supseteq \mathbb{S}^2 = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$ the unit sphere and $X=\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash N$ with $N=(0,0,1)$, then $E = \mathbb{S}^2 \cap \{z=0\}$ and $Y=X/E$ the space where $E$ is identified as a point. $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ is the canonical projection.

Show that:

1. $\pi$ is a closed map, but not an open map
2. Is $Y$ compact?
3. Is $Y$ connected?
4. Is $Y \backslash \{ \pi (E)\}$
   connected?

I think I can do 2, 3 and 4:

2. $Y$ is not compact because $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (because it has a "hole" on $N$...): if $Y$ was compact then $X$ would be compact: fix $(A)_{i\in I}$ a open cover of $X$. I know $X \cap \{ z \leq t \}$ for some $t>0$ is compact so I just have to find a subcover of $X \cap \{ z \geq t \}$. If $Y$ was compact then there is a fine subcover of $Y \cap \{ z \geq t \}$ so I could choose $\pi^{-1}(A_i)$ as a finite subcover of $X \cap \{ z \geq t \}$.
3. $Y$ is connected because it is quotient of $X$ which is path connected, and so $Y$ itself is path connected.
4. If I call $C^+$ the northern emisphere of $Y$ and $C^-$ the southern one, they are both open and $Y \backslash \{ \pi (E)\} = C^+ \sqcup C^-$

I don't know how to answer the first question. I kinda see that it have something to do with the fact that $\pi(E)$ is closed in $Y$, but I'm not sure how to do it. I also have tried to describe the image of open and closed subsets of $X$ but achieved nothing.

Also in the fourth question I kinda cheated because I am not actually sure that $C^+$ and $C^-$ are open, even if my intuition says so. My doubt is: I can see $X$ as subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is it the same for $Y$?

Thank you very much, sorry for the long post.

Comment: I see that $C^+$ and $C^-$ are open because their preimage are open in $X$

Comment: For the next time, try to avoid asking multiple questions in one question.

Comment: For 2., you define $\{A_i\}$ to be an open cover of $X$, then later talk about $\pi^{-1}(A_i)$, which does not make sense.  I don't think this approach is going to work even if you do find a way to clarify what it means, since as you have shown $\pi$ is not open, so if you start with an open cover $\{A_i\}$ of $X$, the images $\{\pi(A_i)\}$ will generally not constitute an open cover of $Y$.

Comment: @MW I messed with notation, however I was thinking that $\pi$ restricted to $X\cap \{ z > r >0 \}$ and $Y\cap \{ z > r > 0 \}$ is homeomorphism, so there is a canonical bijection between open sets. So what I call $\pi^{-1}(A_i)$ is actually the preimage of the finite subcover in $Y$ (I also called them $A_i$ which is probably confusing and misleading)

Comment: @Folpo13 it’s not clear at all what your argument is then.  If you are beginning with an open cover of $X$, you need to show the entire open cover has a finite sub cover.  At some point you need to have an open cover of $Y$ if you are going to invoke compactness of $Y$, and you cannot get such a cover by looking at images under $\pi$ since $\pi$ is not an open map.  The restriction to $\{z>r>0\}$ being a homeomorphism doesn’t mean that any of the $A_i$’s that you begin with have open images, since none of them have to be contained in $\{z>r>0\}$ to begin with.

Comment: Now, you could observe that if $Y$ is compact, then $ \pi(X\cap\{z\geq r\})$ is a closed subset of a compact set (since $X\cap\{z\geq r\}$ is saturated and closed, it’s image is closed), hence must also be compact, and then observe that for $r>0$, since $\pi$ gives a homeomorphism between $X\cap\{z\geq r\}$ and $Y\cap \pi(\{z\geq r\})$, we would have to have $X\cap\{z\geq r\}$ be compact, but the latter set is not closed in $\mathbb R^3$, so not compact.  That argument would in fact work.

Comment: @MW start with any cover of $X$. I know $X = K^+ \cup K^-$ where $K^+=X \cap \{ z \geq r > 0\}$ and $K^-=X \cap \{ z \leq r > 0\}$ for a certain fixed $r$. I know $K^-$ is compact, so if I have a open cover of $X$, I know I have a finite subcover of $C^-$, so I have to show that $C^+$ is compact. But $C^+$ is not compact, because it's not closed. Since $\pi$ restricted to $C^+$ is homeomorphism, $Y$ compact implies $C^+$ compact (since it's homeomorphic to $Y \cap \{ z \geq r\}$ which is a closed subset of a compact), which is false. So $Y$ can't be compact. This is what I thought

Comment: Maybe the first part is unnecessary, because $Y$ compact implies $C^+$ compact, which I can already say is not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151162/discussion-between-m-w-and-folpo13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Take a closed set $A$ on $X$. Then $\pi(A)$ is closed:

If $A$ doesn't contain a point of $E$, then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(A))=A$ which is closed so $\pi(A)$ is closed by definition. If $A$ does contain points of $E$ then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(A))=A\cup E$ which is closed since it is a finite union of closed sets, so $\pi(A)$ is closed by definition.

This means $\pi$ is a closed map.

To show that it isn't an open map, we have to find an open set that gets mapped onto a set that is not open. Take for example $B=\{(x,y,z)\in X\mid x>0\}$. Then $\pi(B)$ is not open since $\pi^{-1}\pi(B)=B\cup E$ is not open.

Therefore $\pi$ is not open.

**Question 2**

As Goki mentioned in the comments, $X$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it is not closed which is enough for it to be not compact.

**Question 3**

Your reasoning is right. Alternatively, you can show it directly like this: Path connectedness and connectedness are two different things. Use the fact that if $Y$ was the union of two disjoint clopen, then its preimage would give two disjoint closed sets (since $\pi$ is a closed map) whose union is $X$, which would mean $X$ is not connected. This is a contradiction.

**Question 4**

$C^+$ and $C^-$ are both open since $\pi^{-1}(C^{+/-})$ is open. That is by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) (a set is open/closed if its preimage is open/closed under the canonical projection).

Comment: Answer to question 2 is not good beacause $X$ is not open in $\mathbf{R}^3$.

Comment: Ah ye fair, but it's not closed

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For question 3: I know that path connectedness and connectedness are different, but path connected implies connected.

Comment: Ah yes it has been some time, that should work as well, Let me edit it

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. I didn't think to use the characterization of open and closed sets in $Y$ as sets such that their preimage is open/closed in $X$, which is actually their definition

Comment: Yes indeed, that is pretty necesary to solve the questions. Please consider marking my answer as the answer if it answers your questions.

Comment: I don't think the reasoning in 2.) is quite there.  What does whether or not $X$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$ have to do with anything?  We are not taking a quotient of $\mathbb R^3$.  I might be missing something here. We are not trying to show $X$ is noncompact, we are trying to show $Y$ is noncompact.

Comment: regarding my previous comment, I guess OP purports to show that $Y$ compact implies $X$ compact, but I'm not sure OP's argument for 2) makes sense either -  they start with an open cover of $X$, but somehow are supposed to use the (assumed for contradiction) compactness of $Y$, but there is no reason for the images of the open cover in $X$ to be open, since the quotient map is not open.

Comment: FWIW, to argue noncompactness I would simply observe directly that if $U_t:=X\cap \{z<t\}$, then $\{U_t\mid t<1\}$ is an open cover of $X$ by **saturated** open sets, with no finite subcover, and therefore the images form an open cover of $Y$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Also, in 3), there is zero reason to use that $\pi$ is a closed map.  The continuous image of a connected set is connected, period, so since $X$ is connected, $Y$ is as well.  If you didn't have this fact about connectivity available, the one-line proof would be that if $U$ is clopen, then its pre-image is clopen by continuity of $\pi$.

Comment: @MW, but since $\pi$ isn't an open map, can we easily guarantee that the image of each $U_t$ is open? That may follow from the fact that each $U_t$ is saturated (or perhaps, saturated with respect to $\pi$?), but I am unfamiliar with those concepts. It seems to me that $Y$ is a one-point compactification of $C^+\sqcup C^-,$ and so *is* compact, but I may be missing something (else).

Comment: @CameronBuie $U_t$ “saturated” just means $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_t))=U_t$.  Once you know that, $\pi(U_t)$ is open by definition of the quotient topology.  $Y$ is not the one-point compactification of $C^+\cup C^-$.  Remember the North Pole was removed, so $C^+$ is a punctured disk.

Comment: @MW Oh! Ha! I had removed the intersection of the equator and the "prime meridian," instead, as it were. No wonder it wasn't making sense! Thank you for setting me straight and clearing up my gap in terminology.